# Build Embedded QT5 for beagleboard

Tags: linux, embedded, qt5

i got some error for build Embedded QT5 for beagleboard

1. QT configure
   ./configure -prefix /home/nirvana/ti-sdk-beagleboard-06.00.00.00/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.0-master/Out -release -opensource -platform linux-g++-32 -xplatform qws/linux-TIarmv7-sgx-g++ -no-pch -no-glib -no-cups -no-nis -no-gtkstyle -opengl es2 -confirm-license  -no-xcb -no-wayland -no-glib  -verbose  -eglfs -no-c++11 -no-accessibility -system-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -no-openvg -widgets -no-tslib -make libs -make tools -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/home/nirvana/ti-sdk-beagleboard-06.00.00.00/linux-devkit/sysroots/i686-arago-linux/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-

2.QMAKESPEC
export QMAKESPEC=""

3. make -j4

   -L/home/nirvana/ti-sdk-beagleboard-06.00.00.00/Graphics_SDK_4_09_00_01/gfx_rel_es5.x/ -L/home/nirvana/ti-sdk-beagleboard-06.00.00.00/tslib-1.0/out/lib -L/home/nirvana/ti-sdk-beagleboard-06.00.00.00/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.0-master/qtbase/lib -lQt5Core -lEGL -lGLESv2 -lGLES_CM -lIMGegl -lsrv_um -lusc -lts -lpthread -lqtharfbuzzng -L/home/nirvana/ti-sdk-beagleboard-06.00.00.00/Graphics_SDK_4_09_00_01/gfx_rel_es5.x/ -L/home/nirvana/ti-sdk-beagleboard-06.00.00.00/tslib-1.0/out/lib -lts -lz -lEGL -lGLESv2 -lGLES_CM -lIMGegl -lsrv_um -lusc 
   .obj/qimage.o: In function `QImage::fill(unsigned int)':
   qimage.cpp:(.text+0x3926): undefined reference to`qt_memfill32(unsigned int*, unsigned int, int)'
   qimage.cpp:(.text+0x3a7a): undefined reference to `qt_memfill32(unsigned int*, unsigned int, int)'
   .obj/qimage_conversions.o: In function`qInitImageConversions()':
   qimage_conversions.cpp:(.text+0x3458): undefined reference to `convert_RGB888_to_RGB32_neon(QImageData*, QImageData const*, QFlags<Qt::ImageConversionFlag>)'
   .obj/qdrawhelper.o: In function`void qt_rectfill(unsigned int*, unsigned int, int, int, int, int, int)':
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x6578): undefined reference to `qt_memfill32(unsigned int*, unsigned int, int)'
   .obj/qdrawhelper.o: In function`void qt_bitmapblit_template(QRasterBuffer*, int, int, unsigned int, unsigned char const*, int, int, int)':
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x6caa): undefined reference to `qt_memfill32(unsigned int*, unsigned int, int)'
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x6ccc): undefined reference to`qt_memfill32(unsigned int*, unsigned int, int)'
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x6dce): undefined reference to `qt_memfill32(unsigned int*, unsigned int, int)'
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x6df6): undefined reference to`qt_memfill32(unsigned int*, unsigned int, int)'
   .obj/qdrawhelper.o:qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x6e0e): more undefined references to `qt_memfill32(unsigned int*, unsigned int, int)' follow
   .obj/qdrawhelper.o: In function`qInitDrawhelperAsm()':
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x1b6f8): undefined reference to `qt_blend_rgb32_on_rgb32_neon(unsigned char*, int, unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int)'
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x1b6fc): undefined reference to`qt_blend_argb32_on_argb32_neon(unsigned char*, int, unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int)'
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x1b700): undefined reference to `qt_blend_argb32_on_rgb16_neon(unsigned char*, int, unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int)'
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x1b704): undefined reference to`qt_blend_rgb16_on_argb32_neon(unsigned char*, int, unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int)'
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x1b708): undefined reference to `qt_blend_rgb16_on_rgb16_neon(unsigned char*, int, unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int)'
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x1b710): undefined reference to`qt_scale_image_argb32_on_rgb16_neon(unsigned char*, int, unsigned char const*, int, int, QRectF const&, QRectF const&, QRect const&, int)'
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x1b714): undefined reference to `qt_scale_image_rgb16_on_rgb16_neon(unsigned char*, int, unsigned char const*, int, int, QRectF const&, QRectF const&, QRect const&, int)'
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x1b718): undefined reference to`qt_transform_image_argb32_on_rgb16_neon(unsigned char*, int, unsigned char const*, int, QRectF const&, QRectF const&, QRect const&, QTransform const&, int)'
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x1b720): undefined reference to `qt_transform_image_rgb16_on_rgb16_neon(unsigned char*, int, unsigned char const*, int, QRectF const&, QRectF const&, QRect const&, QTransform const&, int)'
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x1b724): undefined reference to`qt_alphamapblit_quint16_neon(QRasterBuffer*, int, int, unsigned int, unsigned char const*, int, int, int, QClipData const*)'
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x1b72c): undefined reference to `qt_blend_argb32_on_argb32_scanline_neon(unsigned int*, unsigned int const*, int, unsigned int)'
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x1b734): undefined reference to`comp_func_solid_SourceOver_neon(unsigned int*, int, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x1b738): undefined reference to `comp_func_Plus_neon(unsigned int*, unsigned int const*, int, unsigned int)'
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x1b73c): undefined reference to`qt_destFetchRGB16_neon(unsigned int*, QRasterBuffer*, int, int, int)'
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x1b740): undefined reference to `qt_destStoreRGB16_neon(QRasterBuffer*, int, int, unsigned int const*, int)'
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x1b748): undefined reference to`qt_memrotate90_16_neon(unsigned char const*, int, int, int, unsigned char*, int)'
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x1b74c): undefined reference to `qt_memrotate270_16_neon(unsigned char const*, int, int, int, unsigned char*, int)'
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x1b750): undefined reference to`qt_fetch_radial_gradient_neon(unsigned int*, Operator const*, QSpanData const*, int, int, int)'
   .obj/qdrawhelper.o: In function `void qt_rectfill<unsigned int>(unsigned int*, unsigned int, int, int, int, int, int)':
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x6590): undefined reference to`qt_memfill32(unsigned int*, unsigned int, int)'
   .obj/qdrawhelper.o: In function `rasterop_solid_NotSource(unsigned int*, int, unsigned int, unsigned int)':
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x65f4): undefined reference to`qt_memfill32(unsigned int*, unsigned int, int)'
   .obj/qdrawhelper.o: In function `comp_func_solid_Source(unsigned int*, int, unsigned int, unsigned int)':
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x67a2): undefined reference to`qt_memfill32(unsigned int*, unsigned int, int)'
   .obj/qdrawhelper.o: In function `comp_func_Clear(unsigned int*, unsigned int const*, int, unsigned int)':
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x6906): undefined reference to`qt_memfill32(unsigned int*, unsigned int, int)'
   .obj/qdrawhelper.o: In function `comp_func_solid_Clear(unsigned int*, int, unsigned int, unsigned int)':
   qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x6a6a): undefined reference to`qt_memfill32(unsigned int*, unsigned int, int)'
   .obj/qdrawhelper.o:qdrawhelper.cpp:(.text+0x6c1e): more undefined references to `qt_memfill32(unsigned int*, unsigned int, int)' follow
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   make[3]: *** [../../lib/libQt5Gui.so.5.4.0] Error 1
   make[3]: Leaving directory`/home/nirvana/ti-sdk-beagleboard-06.00.00.00/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.0-master/qtbase/src/gui'
   make[2]: *** [sub-gui-make_first] Error 2
   make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nirvana/ti-sdk-beagleboard-06.00.00.00/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.0-master/qtbase/src'
   make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
   make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/nirvana/ti-sdk-beagleboard-06.00.00.00/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.0-master/qtbase'
   make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
   nirvana@nirvana:~/ti-sdk-beagleboard-06.00.00.00/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.0-master$

have any ideal?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem simply forcing Qt to compile “neon” support for ARM processor, simply modifying the following lines in “qtbase/mkspecs/qmodule.pri” after “./configure”:

```
host_build {
    QT_CPU_FEATURES.i386 =
} else {
    QT_CPU_FEATURES.arm = neon
}
```

Comment: Dear sir:

i use objdump tool to check qt_memfill32  in qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.0/qtbase/src/gui/.obj/qdrawhelper.o 

and i find something as below

 323: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _Z12qt_memfill32Pjji

i think NOTYPE mean is no compiler?

Comment: No, I don't think. NOTYPE is part of symbol table, where Type = symbol type:  Func = Function, Object, File (source file name), Section = memory section, Notype = untyped absolute symbol or undefined

Comment: so, i am think the rootcause of this problem is qdrawhelper.o didn't have
qt_memfill32 symbol,  is it concept correct?

Comment: No, I don't think so. This means that qt_memfill32 has been left for the linker to find the address of the function. This beacause of it is global, and qt_memfill32 is placed into another object  file.

Comment: thanks sir, 

why i use your suggestion for fix this problem as below

host_build {
    QT_CPU_FEATURES.i386 =
} else {
    QT_CPU_FEATURES.arm = neon
}

but the error still occured?

Comment: I don't know. Something related to sdk or toolchain extracted from yocto, maybe...

Comment: Dear LPs:

1. i use ezsdk for beagleboard
2. how to confirm symbol qt_memfill32 is success build-in qdrawhelper.o

Comment: I have no experience with ezsdk. I'm sorry but I don't know how to help you.